# Undefined control sequence using a custom environment using overleaf

Tags: errors, environments

I'm trying to define a custom environment in the following manner:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{rqbox}
    \textbf{RQ2.} \emph{
    How do source .....?
    }
\end{rqbox}
\end{center} 
\smallskip
```

However, I received the following compilation error: "Undefined control sequence" at the line `\begin{rqbox}`

I also posted the definition of the `rqbox`

```
\newenvironment{rqbox}{\par\begingroup
\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\findlength
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\noindent
\hsize=0.95\linewidth
\begin{minipage}{0.95\linewidth}\normalsize}
{\end{minipage}\egroup
% \vspace{6pt}
\textcolor{gray20}{\fboxsep1.5pt\fbox
    {\fboxsep5pt\colorbox{gray05}{\normalcolor\box0}}}
% \endgroup\par\addvspace{6pt minus 3pt}\noindent
\endgroup\par\noindent
\normalcolor\ignorespacesafterend}
\let\Examplebox\examplebox
\let\endExamplebox\endexamplebox
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting code fragments, it's more helpful to put the fragments into a compilable (even with error) document that people can play with.

Comment: Also, the line reported is the point at which TeX gets lost and is not as relevant as the actual content of the error. Can you add the exact text of the error message? The control sequence at the end of the error line is the one that is undefined. What is that?

Comment: unrelated to your question but do not finish `\par\noindent` (will produce a spurious empty paragraph) or `\normalcolor` (does nothing as the group ends at that point and resets the color)

Answer (score 1):

Please always post a full document, and show the error.

Here

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{rqbox}{\par\begingroup
\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\findlength
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\noindent
\hsize=0.95\linewidth
\begin{minipage}{0.95\linewidth}\normalsize}
{\end{minipage}\egroup
% \vspace{6pt}
\textcolor{gray20}{\fboxsep1.5pt\fbox
    {\fboxsep5pt\colorbox{gray05}{\normalcolor\box0}}}
% \endgroup\par\addvspace{6pt minus 3pt}\noindent
\endgroup\par\noindent
\normalcolor\ignorespacesafterend}
\let\Examplebox\examplebox
\let\endExamplebox\endexamplebox


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{rqbox}
    \textbf{RQ2.} \emph{
    How do source .....?
    }
\end{rqbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\rqbox ... \setlength {\fboxsep }{5pt}\findlength 
                                                  \setbox 0=\vbox \bgroup \n...
l.22 \begin{rqbox}
                  
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\endrqbox ->\end {minipage}\egroup \textcolor 
                                              {gray20}{\fboxsep 1.5pt\fbox {...
l.26 \end{rqbox}
                
?
```

I could guess `\textcolor` requires `xcolor` but I have no idea of `\findlength`

Note `\end{rqbox}` is the location where the error is found, not the undefined command.

---

so this runs without error

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{gray20}{red}
\colorlet{gray05}{blue}

\newenvironment{rqbox}{\par\begingroup
\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}%\findlength
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\noindent
\hsize=0.95\linewidth
\begin{minipage}{0.95\linewidth}\normalsize}
{\end{minipage}\egroup
% \vspace{6pt}
\textcolor{gray20}{\fboxsep1.5pt\fbox
    {\fboxsep5pt\colorbox{gray05}{\normalcolor\box0}}}
% \endgroup\par\addvspace{6pt minus 3pt}\noindent
\endgroup%\par\noindent
%\normalcolor
\ignorespacesafterend}
\let\Examplebox\examplebox
\let\endExamplebox\endexamplebox


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{rqbox}
    \textbf{RQ2.} \emph{
    How do source .....?
    }
\end{rqbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```